# Origin of Einstein quote "Quantum mechanics: Real Black Magic Calculus"

Tags: physics, reference-request, quantum-mechanics, einstein

The description of the 1993 English translation of *[The Quantum Dice](https://doi.org/10.1201/9781003062950)*, by Ponomarev and Kurchatov, as well as one of the quotes for chapter 2 of *[Quantum Computation and Quantum Information](https://www.cambridge.org/highereducation/books/quantum-computation-and-quantum-information/01E10196D0A682A6AEFFEA52D53BE9AE)*, by Nielsen and Chuang (2000), contain this quote attributed to Einstein:

> Quantum mechanics: Real Black Magic Calculus.

The former reference attributes it to "a letter in 1925". Nielsen and Matsuschak specify that it is a letter to a colleague from that year in their recent essay "[Quantum Mechanics Distilled](https://quantum.country/qm)". And finally, Nielsen tweeted in 2023 that [Chuang had a reference](https://twitter.com/michael_nielsen/status/1664051112121606144) for this quote.

However, neither my Google fu nor (presumably) my Deutsch are up to the task of actually finding the letter in question.

**In what letter does this quote of Einstein's actually occur?**

Comment: Einstein's papers and correspondence are digitized, translated into English and searchable on [Princeton's site](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/papers). There is only one occurrence of "magic" in a 1925 letter (vol. 15, 138 to Besso) and it is not it:"*The most interesting thing that theory has produced recently is the Heisenberg-Born-Jordan theory of quantum states. Such a magic formula, in which infinite determinants (matrices) take the place of Cartesian coordinates!*" Even searches without time restrictions return nothing similar. Maybe Chuang got it from ChatGPT?

Comment: I tried that search too—likewise, searching "calculus" yields nothing useful (certainly not in 1925). It's possible _The Quantum Dice_ is the true origin, I suppose.